# nextjs: Error serializing `.product` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/prints/[name]"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, strapi, encodeuricomponent

I have a Strapi nextjs app with 2 categories of products.
It's all good on local but I have this error when I try to build:

> Error serializing `.product` returned from `getStaticProps` in
> "/prints/[name]". Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON.
> Please use `null` or omit this value all together.

What I don't understand is that it concerne only one category of product while the code is the same.
I know it's not the best config but I couldn't do another way.

**index.js(books)**

```
const HomePage = ({ products }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Catalogue</title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Classe moyenne éditions publie des livres et multiples d'artistes, émergeants ou reconnus, en France et à l'international."
        />
        <meta
          name="keywords"
          content="Edition d'artiste, Livres, prints, multiples, art books, librairie, concept store, Bookshop, Bookstore"
        />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      </Head>
      <Catalogue products={products} />
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const products = await getProducts();
  return { props: { products } };
}

export default HomePage;
```

**index.js(prints)**

```
const CataloguePage = ({ products }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Catalogue Prints</title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Classe moyenne éditions publie des livres et multiples d'artistes, émergeants ou reconnus, en France et à l'international."
        />
        <meta
          name="keywords"
          content="Edition d'artiste, Livres, prints, multiples, art books, librairie, concept store, Bookshop, Bookstore"
        />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      </Head>
      <CataloguePrints products={products} />
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const products = await getProductsPrints();
  return { props: { products } };
}

export default CataloguePage;
```

**[name].js**

```
 export default ProductPage;

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const product = await getProductPrints(params.name);
  return { props: { product } };
}

// This function gets called at build time
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // Call an external API endpoint to get products
  const products = await getProductsPrints();
  // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
  const paths = products.map(
    (product) => `/prints/${product.Name}`
  );
  // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
  // { fallback: false } means other routes should 404.
  return { paths, fallback: false };
}
```

If you also have some advices to avoid repeating almost same code twice i'm interested. The reason is the 2 categories have different json designs

Answer (score 0):

does `await getProducts()` return an array of objects ? `props` expects an object **only**. So you may have to refactor your code a bit before passing it to props.

Comment: Yes, an array of objects. But what I don't understand is why it works fine with books and not with prints while it's pretty much the same

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide your code for getProducts().
I tried it with axios, something like:

```
let { data } = await axios.get(url)
```

Basically, you need 'data' attribute from rest call.
Or, you may try to do console.log(getProducts()), to see the structure of json.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to properly parse the response and it worked fine. It'll be helpful to share your `getProductPrints()` code so we can understand the nature of its response. But in the meantime, try this:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await getProductPrints();
  const products = await res.json()
  return { props: { products } };
}
```